# async-await with console.log works but when I try to use the return statement I'm getting a promise back instead?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, es6-promise, console.log

I'm hoping somebody can point out the error of my ways here.

I have two functions at the moment. One is `getData` and it's an async function that simply makes an API call requesting data. The second function is `getRandomCategories` that encapsulates the `getData` function call and holds the value of that async operation in a variable called `res`. The rest of the code within `getRandomCategories` manipulates the response data to an array of numbers where each number represents a category.

When I use the debugger statement in the `getRandomCategories` function (right before the return statement within the try block) I'm getting the data type I'm expecting from my variable named apiCallCategoryArray - it's an array of numbers each representing a category. Life is good.

Here's what I'm not understanding: If you look at the two function calls towards the bottom of the snippet (`test()` and `testAgain()` they're essentially the same functions but just with different names so I can compare them side-by-side) I'm able to `console.log(res)` in `test()` with the expected return value (an array of numbers) but when I try to return `res` (in `testAgain()`) the variable `myData2` does NOT contain an array of numbers (as what I'm expecting it to contain) instead  it contains: `Promise { <state>: "pending" }`

Here's my code below:

```
async function getData(endpoint, query, value) {
  return await axios.get(
    `http://jservice.io/api/${endpoint}?&${query}=${value}`
  )
}


// createa a function that will return 6 random categories
async function getRandomCategories(data) {
  try {
    const res = await getData('categories', 'count', 50)
    const data = res.data;
    const categories = filterCategoryData(data); // I'm filtering for categories
    const categoryIdArr = mapCategoryIds(categories); // an array of just category Ids
    const shuffledCategoryIds = shuffle(categoryIdArr); // shuffles the array
    const apiCallCategoryArray = takeFirstXItems(shuffledCategoryIds, 6); // takes 6 items
    debugger // values are as expected
    return apiCallCategoryArray
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// this logs what my expected return value should be
async function test() {
  const res = await getRandomCategories()
  console.log(res) //  Array(6) [ 11518, 11537, 11533, 11512, 11542, 11506 ]
}

// But when I try to use the return statement so I can use the array 
// I'm getting a promise back. This NOT my expected return value??
async function testAgain() {
  const res = await getRandomCategories()
  return res // return statement instead of console.log()
}

const myData = test() // the console.log within the test function logs the expected data type
console.log(myData) // but if I console.log myData it logs: Promise { <state>: "pending" }

const myData2 = testAgain() // same function but just a different name but this time I'm using a return statement instead of console.log
console.log(myData2) // Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

My question is: why am I able to `console.log(res)` with the expected return value in `test()`
but when I use the return statement (like in `testAgain()`) I'm getting a Promise { : "pending" } instead of the array of numbers like I'm expecting. Where do I tweak my code so that my variable holds an array of numbers instead of the Promise?

Thanks in advance for everyone's time.

Comment: Your code is calling an `async` function without `await`, so you get a Promise back.

Answer (score 1):

`const data = res.data;` should be `const data = await res.data;` in the `getRandomCategories` function. Also `const myData2 = testAgain()` should be `const myData2 = await testAgain()` but as it is top level code and await needs an async function, you could wrap it into an self-invoking function or use then/catch.

More info about async/await [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).